# Ordering execution of feature files in Cucumber-JVM

Tags: cucumber-jvm, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I am using `Serenity` with `Cucumber-JVM`. `Serenity` helps to generate test reports after execution.

Since by default feature files are picked up in Alphabetical order, report is also in this order.

Is there any workaround in `Cucumber-JVM` to pick up the files in the order they are created in `/features` folder?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to start each feature file with an order number like:

- `001-login-the-web-shop.feature`
- `002-search-for-item.feature`
- etc.